# 会いたかった : What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, kanji, english-to-japanese

I've an instagram friend who is far older than me. One day, he figured out that I lived near his house, then he commented this in my instagram post:

あなたに会いたかった。

What does that mean? Did he want me to meet him directly? Or just hoping we can meet unintentionally?

Comment: http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/068.html

Answer (score 5):

If said by a native speaker,

> 「あなたに会{あ}いたかった。」

could only mean:

> "I've been wanting to meet you (in person)."

which naturally would ***not*** include "bumping into you someplace".

Comment: Wah. Thanks .  What about 会いたい? Is there any difference between them? Or 会いたかった includes some kind of process of "wanting" and 会いたい if translated means "I want to meet"?

Comment: But 「あなたに会いたかった」 can mean "I wanted to meet you" or even something like "I wish I could have met you."...

Comment: @goldbrick , perhaps this is where l'électeur's caveat, "if said by a native speaker" is important. Perhaps given the context, this statement cannot be taken (by a native speaker) as a simple past statement or past potential statement.

Comment: @ericfromabeno The contextual constraint imposed by the condition "if said by a native speaker" could only be that「あなたに会いたかった」is uttered by a native speaker. Any utterance of the sentence, by any native speaker, will satisfy it. It couldn't limit their statement to the matter at hand. Or maybe it could. (See, it's sometimes hard to determine what people mean by what they say.) But my point was that even then we still don't have enough contextual information to rule out those other interpretations.