# How to understand 態度を片付け

Tags: verbs, giving-and-receiving, literature

> 私は奥さんの**態度をどっちかに片付けてもらいたかった**のです。

これも [usage of ぎりで in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61079/usage-of-%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A7-in-this-sentence) とおなじで、夏目漱石の「こころ」の一文です。

この「てもらいたかった」は[これ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60800/29959)によると「てもらいたい」の過去時制だとわかっています。

質問は、

この「てもらいたい」は「てほしい」と同じ意味ですか。

「片付け」は「部屋」や「書類」などに使う語のはずです。いみは「どこかをきれいにする」や「本を種類分けをして本棚に入れる」などのはずです。なぜ「態度」に使うのですか。もしかして「態度を変える」と理解するのでしょうか。

Comment: Another answer: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/10310076

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- この「片づける」は "to settle down", "to sort out" のような意味で使われています。現代文でも「問題を片づける」「トラブルを片づける」などと言うことができます。ただし、現代文で「態度を片づける」ということはまれだと思います。私なら「態度を決める」「態度について[片**を**つける](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%87%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)」などと言うと思います。
- この文の場合は、「～てもらいたい」と「～てほしい」はほとんど同じです。ただし、「～てもらいたい」の方が、話者自身に直接利益があるという印象が強くなります。例えば「ヤンキースに優勝してもらいたい」と言うと、まるでヤンキースの関係者が言っているように聞こえるかもしれません。単なるファンとして応援している場合は「ヤンキースに優勝して欲しい」というのが普通でしょう。

Comment: "私は奥さんに自分で自分の態度を決めてほしい"と理解すればいいですか

Comment: @HING はい、だいたいそういう意味です。