# 書類や資料などの内容の引用について

Tags: usage, expressions

My English isn't good, so I have always asked in Japanese, but Japanese isn't my mother tongue either. Sometimes, when I'm asking a question in Japanese, the question and the example are related to a textbook or a novel, so I have to show where the example comes from.

For example:

[How to understand 態度を片付け](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/how-to-understand-%E6%85%8B%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%92%E7%89%87%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91)

In this question, the example is from a Japanese novel which is Natsume Soseki's Kokoro.

> 私は奥さんの態度をどっちかに片付けてもらいたかったのです。

How do I tell everybody this sentence is from a Natsume novel?

I've tried the following examples before but maybe they are unnatural in Japanese.

> これは夏目漱石のこころにおける文の一つです
>
> 夏目漱石のこころにはこれが書いてあります
>
> 夏目漱石のこころには「」と書いてあります

but [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/61079/revisions) must be correct:

> これは夏目漱石の「こころ」の一文です

Any other way to show a source in Japanese?

Comment: Another answer here: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/10354115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

１文を引用する場合は・・・

> ｛これは / 以下は｝夏目漱石の『こころ』の一文です。
>   ｛これは / 以下は｝夏目漱石の『こころ』の中の一文です。
>   ｛これは / 以下は｝夏目漱石の『こころ』からの一文です。

"This is / The following is a sentence in/from *Kokoro* by Soseki Natsume."

引用がそれより長い場合は・・・

> 以下は夏目漱石の『こころ』からの｛引用 /（一部）抜粋｝です。
>   以下は夏目漱石の『こころ』（から）の一節です。
>   以下は夏目漱石の『こころ』の一部です。

"The following is a quotation/excerpt/passage from *Kokoro* by Soseki Natsume."

引用文の後にこのように付け加えてもいいと思います：

> -- 夏目漱石『こころ』より

Comment: How to type 『』in Google Japanese IME with Standard US Keyboard?

Comment: @HING 「かっこ」ってひらがなで打って変換したら、候補に出ます。[こんな感じで。](https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/43310145_1906809002760307_8017763391038816256_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&oh=8aeae53d9fb637dbc472b6e01e021c8b&oe=5C182C06) 出ます？